# What does “Mr/s” mean, in a greeting?

Tags: forms-of-address

I received a note addressed to “Mr/s Eric [my last name].” Both on the front of the envelope and in the greeting of the message.

Is this shorthand for Mr & Mrs?

Comment: Must be because they don't know which you are: Mr or Ms or Mrs

Answer (score -1):

Its was essentially “sir or madam”.  S/he...its “Mr or Mrs”.  Make sense?